# How to measure latency, delay, packet loss, bandwidth , response time in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm just wondering how can I measure these things in my Application that run in Android Studio?

- Latency
- Delay time
- Packet loss
- Bandwidth
- Response time

I'm new to android studio and I just created my Apps that communicate with the cloud server which is 000Webhost. I know in the android studio there some way to measure network, but it only measures sizes of packets(Sending/Receiving) using **Profiler**. By the way, I run my application using a smartphone connected to a laptop using the USB connection

Is there any better way for me where I can measure all those things that I have mentioned just now?. Much appreciated if you could help me. Thank you